# Creating simple device driver in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am new to Linux driver development. I am creating very simple device driver. Firstly I register my device at 250 0 call it rday. By calling (assuming I have `chardrv.c` file that does it):

My `chardrv.c` file:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#include <linux/types.h>    // for dev_t typedef
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>   // for format_dev_t
#include <linux/fs.h>       // for alloc_chrdev_region()
#include <linux/cdev.h>     // for "struct cdev"
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    // for user/kernel space copy routines

static dev_t mydev;
static char buffer[64];

static char output[] = "Victory is mine!\n";

ssize_t
my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "In chardrv read routine.\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Count field is %lu.\n", count);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Offset is %lu.\n", *f_pos);

    if (output[*f_pos] == '\0') {
        printk(KERN_INFO "End of string, returning zero.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    copy_to_user(buf, &output[*f_pos], 1);
    *f_pos += 1;
    return 1;  // returned a single character
}

struct cdev my_cdev;

struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = my_read,
};

static int __init chardrv_in(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "module chardrv being loaded.\n");

    alloc_chrdev_region(&mydev, 0, 1, "rday");
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", format_dev_t(buffer, mydev));

    cdev_init(&my_cdev, &my_fops);
    my_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    cdev_add(&my_cdev, mydev, 1);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit chardrv_out(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "module chardrv being unloaded.\n");

    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(mydev, 1);
}

module_init(chardrv_in);
module_exit(chardrv_out);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Robert P. J. Day, http://crashcourse.ca");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This one registers my device driver and it can only print messages.
    cat /proc/devices

I check if it was registered, here is the output:

```
....
250 rday
251 hidraw
...
etc
```

I create file for that driver using:

```
sudo mknod /dev/victoryismine c 250 0
```

Then if I check using:

```
ls -l /dev/victoryismine
```

I am able to locate that file. But running:

```
cat /dev/victoryismine
```

I get an error:

> No Such device or address.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I guess that `mknod` is not very friendly (or compatible) with  `udev` or `systemd`

Comment: What's the output of ls -l` ?

Comment: @Amessihel it shows /dev/victoryismine directory,

Comment: @user3565829, **what is the output** of `ls -l` ????   We want to see the output, not you seeing it and telling us that you see it.  Please, post the output contents, not a comment that there is some output.  See the difference in the question we ask to what you are responding?